# DefaultTabelModel class cast exception when extending

Tags: java, swing, vector, classcastexception, defaulttablemodel

```
List<MyProduct> myProducts = getMyProducts();//create an arraylist;
Vector dataVector = new Vector(myProducts);
Vector columnVector = new Vector(myColNames); //Just a list of string headers
setDataVector(dataVector, columnVector);
```

[setDataVector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) calls this piece of code in DefaultTableModel and throws classcast exception where highlighted, which looks like a bug ? As it is trying to cast the element to a vector, which doesn't make sense.

```
private void justifyRows(int from, int to) {
        // Sometimes the DefaultTableModel is subclassed
        // instead of the AbstractTableModel by mistake.
        // Set the number of rows for the case when getRowCount
        // is overridden.
        dataVector.setSize(getRowCount());

        for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
            if (dataVector.elementAt(i) == null) {
                dataVector.setElementAt(new Vector(), i);
            }
            //java.lang.ClassCastException:
            ((Vector)dataVector.elementAt(i)).setSize(getColumnCount());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stacktrace please, note that you should not use raw type..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<MyProduct> myProducts = getMyProducts(); //create an arraylist;
Vector dataVector = new Vector(myProducts);
```

This makes `dataVector` a vector of `MyProduct` not a vector of vector. I think that is your problem.

Comment: the constructor docs says "Constructs a vector containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator."

Comment: my bad, but it's still your problem, elements are of type `MyProduct` not `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException:
  ((Vector)dataVector.elementAt(i)).setSize(getColumnCount());
```

`setDataVector(Vector dataVector, Vector columnIdentifiers)`: Actually expects a `Vector` containing  one or more `Vector`:representing table data `rows`. You will understand better if you compare with other function `setDataVector(Object[][] dataVector, Object[] columnIdentifiers)`.

After returning your `ArrayList` myProducts, add this create a `Vector` e.g., `prodVect` containing the elements of the list and add the vector to another `Vector`:

```
List<MyProduct> myProducts = getMyProducts();//create an arraylist;
Vector prodVector = new Vector(myProducts);
Vector dataVector = new Vector();
dataVector.add(prodVector);
setDataVector(dataVector, columnVector);
```

But instead of depending on `setDataVector` function, i think you could use `model.addRow(prodVector)` where `prodVector` is a `Vector` as defined above. Another one is `model.addRow(Object[])` function, which you might be aware of and preferable over using the function with `Vector` parameter.